# How to ignore updating null property in Phalcon Model?

Tags: phalcon

How to update a `Model` by ORM in Phalcon without updating its null properties?

I have tried with update or save function but it results the row with null value

*Update:*

I've tried with Class:

```
class Company extends Model {  
    public $id;   // Primary key
    public $name;
    public $brand;

    public function initialize()
    {
         $this->useDynamicUpdate(true);
    } 

    public function getSource()
    {
        return 'company';
    }
  }
```

then I updated by:

```
$company = new Company();
$company->id = 15;
$company->name = 'New Company';
$company->update();
```

Final field `brand` on effected row goes `NULL`
I'm using Phalcon 2.0.6

Comment: Can you show us short DB schema and your ORM code? Please update your question.

Comment: If you add `$this->useDynamicUpdate(true);` to the `initialize` method of your model, then you will only update the fields which you have changed. (instead of updating all fields)

Comment: @Timothy It's only true while I using phalcon 2.0. But it has been removed in phalcon 3.0 :((

Comment: @NguyễnHoàngViệt check the [3.0 docs](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.1/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model.html), it's there.

Answer (score 0):

result dependency of table type ....

try this:

```
$company = new Company();
$company->id = 15;
$company->name = 'New Company';
$company->update();
$company->refresh();
```

or use

```
afterFetch()
```